# Adding controls to manipulate Animation in Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning to work with Html5 Canvas. How can I add two buttons that will decrease or increase the speed of the animated square in the canvas? I am a beginner at programming so I am trying to keep it simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="ex1" width="525" height="200" style = "border: 5px solid black;"</canvas>
  <script>

    var x =  0;
    var y = 15;
    var speed = 10;

    function animate() {

    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame
            ;

    reqAnimFrame(animate);

    x += speed;

    if(x <= 0 || x >= 475)
      {
       speed = -speed;
       }

    draw();
   }


function draw() {
var canvas  = document.getElementById("ex1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 170);
context.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
context.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
}

animate();
 </script>
 <p></p>
 <audio controls>
  <source src="fortworth.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="fortworth.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 button in html like this:

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="btnAdd">
```

and in javascript, bind the button to the click event like this:

```
document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//Here you do your logic
speed++;
});
```

You do the same thing for the speed--;

Edit: Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ELpPv/1/)

Comment: This seems to be working but my math is wrong somewhere. After clicking the + button 7 times it will jump to a negative number. Ex I click the + goes to 6,7,8,9,10 then will jump to -9. See where I went wrong??

Comment: Ahhh the negative number is because when your square is changing direction! from left to right, the speed is positive, and right to left, it's negative. I added a bool to know when it's going right, look at my event on the button, that's where I look wether i need to add or substract: [NEW COOL FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xS4j2/)

Comment: I just want to add that the negative was normal because you were doing speed = -speed;

Comment: I updated my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xS4j2/1/) with comment to help you understand what I did better.